# Trapping Perl backticks on non-zero return codes

Tags: perl

I'd like know if it is possible to trap (call a subroutine) every time a Perl backticks (quote) operator returns a non zero error code instead of checking `$? >> 8` after each call.

Is it possible?

Comment: You should override core function, but in case of `qx` it doesn't work. http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html#OVERRIDING-CORE-FUNCTIONS

Comment: @mpapec, That won't work. If you created a function named `qx` using `use subs`, you'd have to change change the backticks to double-quotes, so you might as use a name that doesn't conflict. And you can't override `qx` globally that way since it doesn't have a proptotype since it's not function-like.

Comment: @ikegami `use subs 'qx';` doesn't work as I mentioned above.

Comment: @mpapec, Maybe you meant "You *can* override core functions"? Otherwise, I don't know what point you were trying to make. (Note that you *can* achive what the OP wants for both `qx` and backticks by hooking into the opcode checker, or by entirely replacing `qx` as I did for `qw` in Syntax::Feature::QwComments.)

Comment: @ikegami the point is that core functions can be overridden, but `qx` unfortunately isn't, although it damn looks like one.

Comment: @mpapec, Looks like one? I didn't know you could do `qx(join " ", $cmd, @args)`... The fact that it *doesn't* look like a sub is the entire reason it can't be simply overridden.

Comment: @ikegami obviously we have different definitions of what falls into `looks like` category.

Comment: @mpapec, To me and to Perl, a sub call involve a name and an argument list.

Answer (score 4):

[IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::System::Simple)'s `capture` is a version of backticks that throws an exception on error.

Comment: IPC::System::Simple isn't a core module.

Comment: @Slade, oops! It's used by a core module, so I thought it was one.

Comment: `perl -e'use autodie qw( system );'`

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the backticks in a function that implements the error checking and call that instead. That would be implementing a hooking system yourself.

```
sub call_backticks {
  my ($command, $callback) = @_;

  my $output = `$command`;
  return $callback->($command, $?) if $? >> 8;
  return $output;
}

# later...

my $output = call_backticks('cat /var/log/messages', sub { print Dumper @_; });
```

That would give you basic handling on this. But there is no general hooking up to stuff in Perl.